# NSURLSession delegate didCompleteWithError not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have the below implementation of `NSURLSession` .

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                               delegate:self
                                                               delegateQueue: nil];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
[task resume];        
while(!finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100000]];
}
```

and i have implemented the below delegate methds:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aresponse  
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error  
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition,
                         NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
```

the "finished" variable for while loop above is set to 1 when `didCompleteWithError` delegate is received when indicates that there is some issue like network down, etc...

When network is down, i don't get `didCompleteWithErrorcallback` , hence the while loop does not exit even though 10sec timeout has been specified and my app crashes giving **Memory warning**.

I do properly receive didReceiveData, didReceiveResponse callback in all scenarious .have not checked  didReceiveChallenge callback though as it requires HTTPs setup here.

so , i have following questions to ask , if you can help me :

1)Why is `didCompleteWithError` callback  not received when network is down?

2)Considering no network issues ,is `didCompleteWithError` callback received on successful completion of task ?If no, what callback would indicate the completion of task , like `connectionDidFinishLoading` when using `NSURLConnection` ?

I have used cachepolicy in the request parameter while starting task. Is it because of this that didcompletewitherror is not called n instead caching delegate should be implemented??

Guys, Please help. I am stuck.

Thankyou

Comment: Don't touch the run loop unless the project is a command line interface without an implicit run loop

Comment: what about other delegate methods? are they called when there is no breakdown in netwrok?

Comment: ok . I got your point . But why is my delegate method not called ? could you please suggest anything ?

Comment: @Mr.T:  Yes, they are called. I forgot to add this ,havenot checked the didReceiveChallenge callback though, as it needs https setup . Others are called . I will update this.

Comment: @user3540903 Because there could have been a failure indicated via a delegate callback that is outside the scope of the task.  As you havent implemented those delegate methods, you are unaware of them.  In other words it won't tell you a task failed if the whole session is broken and once it's told you that (or tried to) it won't even consider the task at all.

Comment: And I assume this is running in a background thread, given you are driving the runloop?

Comment: @Droppy: i have updated my code from NSURLConnection to NSURlSession . with the same set up , in suucess scenario i am getting ConnectionDidfinishLoading and when network is down i get DidFailWithError call back when using NSURLConnection .

Comment: So problem solved then?

Comment: @Droppy: with NSURLsession , i get didRecvResponse and didRecvdata and the purpose of the task is to fetch a key from server, and that is also succesfully done. but i do not recv any callback indicating succefull completiion of task. and when network is down , the apple doc says that you  recv didCompleteWithError callback, but i dont recv it.

Comment: And you've implemented all of the delegate methods now?

Comment: @Droppy: will nsurlsession give me a call back after succesfull completion of task just like didFinishoading when using NSURlConnection?

Comment: Yes; `didCompleteWithError` with the `error == nil`.

Comment: @Droppy: I have implemented [didReceiveData,didReceiveResponse,didCompleteWithError,didReceiveChallenge]. My point , as u say , there seems to be problem beyond the scope of the above delegates, i dont think so. because the same set up gives proper callbacks when using nsurlconnection. Also, there doesnot seem to be any reason why session would get broken when network is down. There could be a problem in my implementation which i am not able to figure out.

Comment: @Droopy: Thankyou. so now as u said didCompleteWithError should come in both cases , when network is down or up. I dont receive in either of the cases. That is whole question. :(

Comment: @Droppy: anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

delegateQueue :[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
instead of instead of delegateQueue :nil did the trick . 
I am still not sure how. But yes, the issue is gone.
could anybody explain how this worked ?

Comment: I'm still having issue that even though I set delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue, my delegate callbacks are still not called.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop "while(!finished)" is really bad practice. Basically the download task is async operation however with your while-loop you are blocking the thread and force the download task to finish in that thread. This might impact system behavior.

I belive removing this loop will solve your problem.